# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS does not boot after update

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

After the last update (admittedly I didnt check what exactly was updated) I cannot boot into Ubuntu 22.04 LTS anymore.
I get stuck during booting at the following screen (after selecting Ubuntu in the GRUB menu):

```
[0.112620] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS 
[1.218058] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.SATO.S PT4._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
[1.221401] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.SATO.SPT4._GTF due to previ ous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529) 
[1.226503] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCIO.SATO.S PT4._GTF.DSSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330) 
[1.227730] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.SATO.SPT4._GTF due to previ ous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529) 
/dev/sdb5: recovering journal 
/dev/sdb5: clean, 444345/2577312 files, 9783268/10289152 blocks 
[5.201763]
```

I am dualbooting with Windows 10. Is there a straightforward way to fix this issue? I am unsure what the actual problem is.
Alternatively, what is the easiest way to make a backup of the data on the computer for a fresh install?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you given this a go?  https://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Comment: No, as I am not even sure it is a grub problem, kernel problem, a hardware problem or something else entirely.